# Calling javascript from Codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have read many different resources but am still not sure if this is possible without using AJAX.

I have a javascript function that loads a div into a modal and says "Loading Please Wait" I have named this funciton loadingModal()

```
function loadingModal(url)
{
     loadModal(...)
}
```

What I need to do is only trigger this after I have verified that the password and username are correct on the server side so:

```
btnSubmit_OnClick(object sender EventArgs e)
{
     string usr;
     string password;

     if (verify(usr, password))
     {
          ///// TRIGGER JAVASCRIPT HERE
          LOAD TONS OF SESSION VARIABLES
          .
          .
          .
      }
      else
         Show Error and Definitely Don't ever mention still loading
 }
```

I know I could just attach an onclientclick call to the javascript however it would load the loading modal even if it was an invalid username and password

Can I trigger javascript mid execution from the server side?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I trigger JavaScript mid execution from the server side?

No. JavaScript code is evaluated on the client-side (in the browser), long after the server-side has finished processing the request. Client-side and server-side scripts are run at different places and at different times. There cannot be that kind of direct interaction.

You could use AJAX, if you do not want to trigger a full page refresh. When you use AJAX, your client (the browser) will issue a fresh new request to the server. The server processes this request (checks username and password, for example) and returns a response (access denied or access granted) back to the client. It is then up to the client to handle the response appropriately.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks for the succinct and straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `add` javascript code to the page, see [`ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359558.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Hope its not too late...

Your best bet is to add 2 asp:Panel: One with a Ajax loading gif that is normally visible until the page is ready and one with style="display:none" and an asp:Label within that panel.

In code-behind, when validation is false, you just change the style to display:inline and set the text of the label to whatever you need. And of course, exit sub without displaying your modal thingy!

Here's an example:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlError" runat="server" style="display:none; position:absolute; left:300; top:300; width:300;">
    <asp:Label ID="lblErr" runat="server" style=" color:Red;"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>

If validation = false Then
        lblErr.Text = "Wrong user name or password or whatever!..."
        pnlLoading.Style.Item("display") = "none"
        pnlError.Style.Item("display") = "inline"
        Exit Sub
End if
```

This way your user will see the loading gif, knowing "something" is in poreparation, and if wrong, he is warned.